# How can I access to MTM fields attribute in my template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, manytomanyfield

I have 3 models: User, Server and Protocol. In my template, I want to display only the list of servers that are accessible by a particular protocol (SSH for example) and user.

models.py:

```
class Protocol(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = ('Protocol name'),
        max_length = 50,
        unique = True,
        default = "Protocol",
        blank = False
    )

    port = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name = ('Port Number'),
        default = 22,
        blank = False,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(65535)]
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        unique = True,
        verbose_name = ('Server name'),
        max_length = 50,
        default = "Server name",
        blank = False
    )

    hostname = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = ('Host name'),
        max_length = 40,
        default = "hostname",
        blank = False
    )

    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(
        verbose_name = ('IP address'),
        protocol = 'ipv4',
        blank=False
    )

    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='User')

    protocol = models.ManyToManyField(Protocol, related_name='Protocol')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

view.py:

```
class ServerListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    queryset = Server.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'servers'
```

template file:

```
          {%for server in servers%}
<a><div>
<h4>{{server.name}}</h4>
<h6>Hostname: {{server.hostname}}</h6>
<h6>IP Address: {{server.ip}}</h6>
</div>
</a>
{%endfor%}
```

Everything works fine. However, I cannot display the protocol associated to each server. I tried these lines but the result is None and it displays nothing!

```
{% for protocol in server.Protocol.all %}
<h1>protocol:  {{ protocol }}</h1>  
{% endfor %}
```

Could anyone help me please!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
{% for protocol in server.Protocol.all %}
```

to

```
{% for protocol in server.protocol.all %}
```

Also note that if you were trying to use `Protocol` because that's the `related_name` then that's actually backwards, it's meant to be used on protocol objects, where you would do `protocol.Protocol.all` to get all the servers --- and so you might want to rename it to `servers` for clarity.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works!! But I still cannot access to the servers that use a particular protocol!
```
                           {% for  server in servers%}
                            {% for protocol in server.protocol.all %}
                             {%if server.protocol.name == SSH%}
  <a><div>
  <h4>{{server.name}}</h4>
  <h6>Hostname: {server.hostname}}</h6>
   <h6>IP Address: {{server.ip}}</h6>
   <h6>Protocol: {{protocol}}</h6>
  </div>
 </a>
                 {%endif%}
           {%endfor%}
           {%endfor%}
```